# Why I get Uncaught Error even after .catch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

Here is the code:

```
function sleep(ms:number)
{
  return new Promise((resolve:any,reject:any) => setTimeout(resolve,ms))
}

async function errorFunc(): Promise<void>
{ 
 await sleep(2000)
 console.log("error throw")
 throw new Error("critical error");
}


let promises: Promise<void>[] = []

for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
  const promise = errorFunc();
  promise.then(()=>console.log("then"))
  promise.catch(()=> console.log("catch"))
  promises.push(promise)
}

async function main()
{
 await Promise.all(promises).catch((e)=>console.log("promise all catch"))
}

main();
```

```js
"use strict";
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function errorFunc() {
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log("error throw");
    throw new Error("critical error");
}
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const promise = errorFunc();
    promise.then(() => console.log("then"));
    promise.catch(() => console.log("catch"));
    promises.push(promise);
}
async function main() {
    await Promise.all(promises).catch((e) => console.log("promise all catch"));
}
main();
```

Here are logs:

```
               error throw
runtime.ts:177 catch
runtime.ts:177 promise all catch
VM193:8 Uncaught (in promise) Error: critical error
```

Isn't the catch supposed to catch an error in Promise?
And actually, error passes through all catches but still at the end "Uncaught"

Comment: The catch block is attached directly to the Promise returned by the errorFunc function, but when using Promise.all, it won't catch errors from individual promises within the array. Instead, you need to handle errors individually for each promise inside the array.

Comment: @Echo  You don't need to handle every promise in a `promise.all`,  the issue the OP has he's started a new promise chain with `then`, and that's not handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `promise.then(() => console.log("then"));` will be returning a new Promise, this promise is then just dangling, it's neither been returned to anything, or handled.  Also note, it's the same for `.catch` it will also be returning a promise that's just dangles, although less likely to cause an issue unless another error is thrown inside the catch.

Like other languages if you want to catch an error, and then continue to propagate this error, what you normally do is re-raise the error.  And this is exactly what you can do with promises.

example, notice how the error is re-thrown, and how everything is a single promise chain.

```js
"use strict";
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function errorFunc() {
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log("error throw");
    throw new Error("critical error");
}
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const promise = errorFunc();
    promises.push(
      promise
        .then(() => console.log("then"))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("catch"); 
          throw e;
        })
    );
}
async function main() {
    await Promise.all(promises).catch((e) => console.log("promise all catch"));
}
main();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning an unguarded promise.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
  const promise = errorFunc();
  const guarded = promise.catch(()=> console.log("catch"))
  promises.push(guarded)
}
```

Return a guarded promise for the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but why? I mean, in the previous code catch was also called. And why in my code, catch on Promise.all() also didn't cought error?

Comment: @Illia `promise.catch()` itself returns a Promise, and that's the one you need to add to your array, not the original one.

Comment: @Pointy I get it, what this catch does, is actually intercept an error, and doesn't reject it further, thank you, for pointing it out!

Comment: @Pointy Actually the promise returned by `promise.catch(…)` is not the problem. It's the `promise.then(…);` that causes the uncaught rejection.

Comment: Oh oh right. (In fact, shouldn't the `.catch()` be on the Promise returned from `.then()`? Funny, since I started using the `async` feature I've forgotten so much about using the Promise APIs directly.)

Comment: This answer has removed `then`, just doing this alone would have stopped the unhandled, like pointed out by @Bergi that was were the issue is, to stop the unhandled, handle the `then`, you can either handle it, or even push this new chain on the the promises array -> `promises.push(promise.then....`, either way the `unhandled` will be gone.

Comment: To add, it's also possible for `catch` to also throw, so if an error is thrown inside `catch`, you will also get an unhandled.  IOW: each time you break a promise chain, you have to handle them individually somehow.